# Timer isn't stoping then restarting after executing method?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, timer

I have been working on this project for the past 3 days till 3-4 am and I believe I know where its messing up (My comments are marking the calculation that I believe is the issue) but as for solving the calculation and if that would even fix the timer I am not sure. I have marked in the code where I believe is the problem but I would accept any opinion on what they believe may fix it or where it is messing up. If it is the one calculation in the (Check) Method then I am not sure what calculation would fix it. If it is something else that someone else see's that I do not please tell me. I have looked at several different options and none seem to work.

This project is meant to test a product, it is to send a message every (x) (sec, mins, hours, days) for (y) (sec, mins, hours, days). () being the users input. After the (x) is elapsed then its time to, stop timer, send method, then restart timer. (ex. (user enters) Send 1 message every (30) sec. for (2) min.) There should be 4 rounds of messages sent but it is ending early due to the timer not stopping. I have an idea of where it is messing up but a little guidance and other opinions would be helpful.

```
    <code>

    private void TimeKeeperTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag == true && EndTime > DateTime.Now)
        {
            _timeKeeper.Stop();
            Check();
            _timeKeeper.Start();
        }

        if (flag == true && EndTime < DateTime.Now)
        {
            TestCompleted();
        }


    }

    bool flag = true;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Method "Check" checks to see it it is time to send a message, time elapsed and time left
    /// </summary>
    private void Check()
    {

        if (SelectedPerfTest != null && flag == true)
        {

            //Est. Date Time Now 
            var ct = DateTime.Now;

            //Time Elapsed Output form now (counts up)
            var te = ct.Subtract(StartTime);
            TimeElapsed = string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", te.Days, te.Hours,
                                        te.Minutes,
                                        te.Seconds);

            // Time Left from now output (counts down)
            var tl = EndTime.Subtract(ct);
            TimeLeft = string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", tl.Days, tl.Hours,
                                        tl.Minutes,
                                        tl.Seconds);


            //Calculate the time til the next message (counting down)
            var nnm = CalculateNextMessage(DateTime.Now);
            NextNewMessage = string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", nnm.Days, nnm.Hours,
                                            nnm.Minutes,
                                            nnm.Seconds);

           //I feel like the Problem is here this equation will call the method to send message but the timer continues to tick... I 
            //need it to stop when the time elapsed that the user put in ex. user enter (send 1 message every (20 seconds)
            //for (2 hours)) it needs to stop in 20 sec. to send message then check if its time to end (if 2 hours are up). 
            //If not send message in another 20 sec.

           if (DateTime.Now.Add(CalculateNextMessage(DateTime.Now)) < DateTime.Now && EndTime > DateTime.Now )

               if (ct.Subtract(StartTime) == LastExecuted.AddMilliseconds(ts).Subtract(ct))
               {
                   if (CurrentProduct == ("Babyware"))
                   {
                       if (SelectedPerfTest == ("Short Test"))
                       {
                           ExecuteShortTest();
                       }
                       if (SelectedPerfTest == ("Long Test"))
                       {
                           ExecuteLongTest();
                       }
                       if (SelectedPerfTest == ("UCN"))
                       {
                           ExecuteUCNTest();
                       }
                   }
                   else
                       if (CurrentProduct == ("Antware"))
                       {
                           if (SelectedPerfTest == ("Short Test"))
                           {
                               ExecuteGAShortTest();
                           }
                           if (SelectedPerfTest == ("Long Test"))
                           {
                               ExecuteGALongTest();
                           }
                       }
               }
        }
    }


    #endregion


  </code>
```

Comment: Please restrict your code sample to a relevant portion. The ideal sample is [short, self-contained and compilable](http://sscce.org/). Reading through an entire source code is time-consuming, and will net you less answers.

Comment: If your `Check` routine throws an exception and your timer is of type `Threading.Timer`, it will circumvent the `Start()` and sometimes not inform you of the exception.  Maybe wrapping `Check()` in `try/finally` and moving the `Start()` call to the `finally` block might help.

Comment: I did try you your suggestion but the timer still will not stop to send the message. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do something like this in the Timer_Tick?

```
If ticks = userTimeInterval Then
  SendMessage()
  Check()
  ticks = 0
Else
   ticks += 1
End If
```

Check the ticks (seconds) against what the user puts in to see if it is time to send the message, if it is then send it. Then check to see if it is time to stop sending the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Before subtracting StartTime and ct make sure it is it the same fortmat as

```
string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", te.Days, te.Hours,
                                        te.Minutes,
                                        te.Seconds);
```

Comment: I double checked the start time and it is formatted correctly. Thanks for the suggestion.